# How do I get the right alias from outlook?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, aliases

I have a database where users are referenced using the alias as a key. I'm writing an outlook plug-in that uses the to, cc, etc. addresses to find data in the database. The problem is that at Microsoft, you can have two aliases: One is a single string, eg: jdoe@microsoft.com. The other is using a dot delimited name: Jane.Doe@microsoft.com. Both are valid addresses for the same person. Is there a way to find all valid aliases, or at least to find the regular e-mail alias from the Jane.Doe one?

I've tried getting the exchange user and getting the folders. Nothing works.

Comment: Note that this is from the Calendar; the e-mail side works fine for my purposes.